# Select more than one option, and receive them in another php

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of users, and here it's possible to select (Standart/Admin). But when I save my `POST`, sends all selected options, but I only want to send the changed ones, because I doesn't make sense to send them all. And when I send this, I need to have the `ID` attached to it, any suggestions on how to do this? the `PrintAll()`, is just something I was trying to do, but can't make it work..

```js
function printAll() {
    var str = "",
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < myForm.UpdateUsers.options.length; i++) {
        if (myForm.UpdateUsers.options[i].selected) {
            str = str + i + " ";
        }
    }
    alert("Options selected are " + str);
}
```

```css
 .ChangeEngine
  {
    font-size: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
   .content2 {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.content2 h2 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 25px 0;
 font-size: 22px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e3;
 color: #4a536e;
}
.content2 > p, .content2 > div {
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 margin: 25px 0;
 padding: 25px;
 background-color: #fff;
}
.content2 > p table td, .content2 > div table td {
 padding: 30px;
}
.content2 > p table td, .content2 > div table td {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #4a536e;
 padding-left: 165px;
}
.content2 > div p {
 padding: 5px;
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.content2 table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.content2 td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.content2 tr {
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.content2 th {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.content2 tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}
```

```html
<div id="EditUsers" class="content2">
    <div>
        <table>
            <form name="myForm" action="UpdateUsers.php" method="post">
                <tr>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Engine</th>
                    <th>Access</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        username
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Engine
                    </td>
                    <td><select class="data" name="UpdateUsers" placeholder="UpdateUsers" id="UpdateUsers">
                            <option>Admin</option>
                            <option>Standart</option>
                        </select></td>
                    <td>
                        id
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <br>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        username
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Engine
                    </td>
                    <td><select class="data" name="UpdateUsers" placeholder="UpdateUsers" id="UpdateUsers">
                            <option>Admin</option>
                            <option>Standart</option>
                        </select></td>
                    <td>
                        id
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" id="ChangeUsers" value="Save" class="btn btn-info ChangeEngine" />
        <input type=submit value="Print All" class="btn btn-info ChangeEngine" onClick="printAll()">
        <br><br>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```